# Visual Studio 2010 loads symbols too slowly when debug mixed application

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mixed-code

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to debug a mixed application. When I attach to that process(Managed + Native), the VS is hung. Then 30 minutes later(not exactly this time, but it's really long), it comes back.

Anybody know how to resolve this?Thanks in advance!

I have 'Delete all breakpoint', tried repair VS and so on. The issue still exists.

Comment: Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols, untick the "Microsoft Symbol Servers" checkbox.

Comment: It's already un-ticked. Turns out that it loads symbols from _NT_SYMBOL_Path since I have cached too much symbols...

Comment: Half an hour worth of symbols?  That's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you have a symbol server that is dead and VS is still trying to get symbols from it  / VS is hitting the MS symbols server which is a slow operation / VS is not finding the symbols in the paths you have, but is still trying to hit them every time and that takes forever (both known issues that we fixed in VS 2012)
If you don't need any symbols - I would do what Hans suggested - Tool/Options/Debugging/Symbols uncheck all symbol servers, plus choose Automatically load symbols for: Only specified modules and specify your modules in that list (it can be empty as well) -> this will work if your app is trying to load a lot of symbols that you don't need. And you can later load them manually (the ones you want) from the Modules window

Comment: Glad to hear! Let me know if you find any symbol weirdness in VS!